# My API request code produces a bug I can't debug or understand

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am not sure where to identify the problem in this code

```
var events = [Events]()

    let URL_GET_DATA = "http://192.168.100.4/PrototypeWebService/api/getevents.php"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        Alamofire.request(URL_GET_DATA).responseJSON{ response in
            if let json = response.result.value {
                print(json)
                let swiftvar = JSON(json).array
                for i in 0..<(swiftvar?.count)! {
                    let jsonObject = swiftvar?[i].object
                    self.events.append(jsonObject as! Events)
                }
                self.EventTable.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect it to create an array of objects of type Events but it produces this error :

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102ca0f4c

Comment: The code is very unsafe, you should wrap the initialization of the `swiftvar` immutable value into an `if let` clause. Additionally, the `jsonObject as! Events` forced cast is a possible failure point and I really doubt that is even downcastable. Please, do attempt to write your code avoiding force casts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are encouraged to drop `SwiftyJSON` in favor of `Codable`.

The error occurs because a (Swifty)JSON object cannot be cast to a custom struct or class.

You have to pass the JSON value to an initializer of the custom struct.

```
struct Event { // it's highly recommended to name this kind of object in singular form
   let varA : String
   let varB : Int

   init(json: JSON) {
      self.varA = json["varA"].string ?? ""
      self.varB = json["varB"].int ?? 0
   }
}
```

And please never use index based loops if you actually don't need the index at all. Create an `Event` instance from the `JSON` object and append it

```
guard let swiftvar = JSON(json).array else { return }
for item in swiftvar {
     let event = Event(json: item)
     self.events.append(event)
}
```

or even simpler

```
guard let swiftvar = JSON(json).array else { return }
self.events = swiftvar.map{ Event(json: $0) }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. Actually I'm a beginner to swift so the codable & decodable concepts are still foreign to me

Comment: If you could help me with a sample tutorial

Comment: Im encountering a runtime error that says **Extra argument 'json' in call** for both options

Comment: In which line ?

Comment: Here : **let event = Events(json: item)**

Comment: You have to add (and adjust) the suggested `init` method in the Event(s) class

Comment: In the Events Class it says **Use of undeclared type JSON**

Comment: As you are using SwiftyJSON anyway it should be available

Comment: I solved it .. I forgot to import SwiftyJSON in the Events Class

Comment: Done with the adjustments .. It still shows **Extra argument 'json' in call**

Comment: I don't know what other initializers the class contains. Is there an `init()` method without parameters? If yes, delete it

Comment: Well it works well with the second option but doesn't display anything in my table

Comment: That's another question

Answer (score 0):

Your code is getting the SwiftJSON API wrong. The culprit is the line

```swift
jsonObject as! Events
```

If you were actually writing the code in a safe manner using `as?` dynamic downcast operator, the compiler would gladly denounce to you that type `Events` and the type of `jsonObject` are parts of separate type hierarchies and thus the downcasting will always fail.

As per SwiftJSON documentation that can be found at https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON the framework does manage deserialization however its basic API does not provide any object population facilities and thus it's the programmers task.

Say, the `Events` type has 2 stored properties, `let string: String` and `let int: Int`.
In order to create an `Events` object off a parsed JSON object, you need to extract the values manually as such

```swift
let string = jsonObject["name"].string
let int = jsonObject["int"].int
```

and then you should pass these values into your own custom-written constructor as such

```swift
let events = Events(string, int)
```

Only after this point you actually will have an Events object that you can use.

Edit: also since the release of Swift 4 there is a `Codable` protocol and a `JSONDecoder` type, which provide a robust, flexible and type-safe facilities to decode your json payloads represented by `Data` object and you should probably ditch the SwiftyJSON because it's an unnecessary dependency.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. Actually I'm a beginner to swift so the codable & decodable concepts are still foreign to me

Comment: If you could help me with a sample tutorial